# How to add a "+" sign in between numbers of the sum?

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a basic c# application that adds numbers through the console, I cannot get the program to display an addition sign between each number.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();

        string calculation = "";
        double sum = 0.0;

        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(calculation)) calculation = arg;
            else calculation =  " + " + args;
            sum = sum + Convert.ToDouble(arg);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sum + calculation);
    }
}
```

Comment: `calculation +=  " + " + arg;` should do the trick

Comment: `else calculation +=  " + " + args;` Or get rid of loop at all: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" + ", args))`

Comment: or jst `calculation = calucluation + " + "  + arg` which is the long version of `+=`.

Comment: FYI - `args != arg`

Comment: FWIW, the problem with `Console.WriteLine(sum + "+" + calculation);` is that it starts with a number, so C# thinks you want to add numbers together and then gets confused by the "+" because it's a string. If you start with a string, it assumes you want to add strings and converts any numbers to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *querying* data (`args` array in your case), try *avoiding loops* and use Linq:

```
    using System.Linq;

    ...

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.Clear();

      // Combine all args with " + "
      string calculation = string.Join(" + ", args);

      // Parse each arg within args then Sum them
      double sum = args.Select(arg => double.Parse(arg)).Sum();

      // Let's use string interpolation to make code be more readable
      Console.WriteLine($"{calculation} = {sum}");
    }
```

If you want good old loop solution

```
    Console.Clear();

    // Appending String in a loop can be time consuming
    // We have a special type for this - StringBuilder
    StringBuilder calculation = new StringBuilder();
    double sum = 0.0;

    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        if (calculation.Length > 0)
            calculation.Append(" + "); 

        calculation.Append(arg);

        sum = sum + Convert.ToDouble(arg);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{sum} {calculation.ToString()}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else calculation +=  " + " + args;
```

'='  is assigns

'+=' is append

Comment: and probably "arg" not "args"

Answer (score 0):

Since calculation will not be null (you initialize it before the loop) you can use a ternary operation to add `arg` and a conditional `" + "` (note the `+=` instead of `=` for the assignment):

```
calculation += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(calculation) ? "" : " + ") + arg;
```

But the same thing can be written using `string.Join` before the loop (note the usage of the `args` array instead of the single `arg` in the loop):

```
calculation = string.Join(" + ", args);
```

For args 1, 2, 3 this will create a string like this: `"1 + 2 + 3"`.
For empty args this will simply return an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___) to rebuild your string array with the `" + "` string.

```
// build the calculation string
string calculation = String.Join(" + ", args);
double sum = 0.0;
// calculate
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    sum += Convert.ToDouble(arg);
}
```

In example :

```
String[] arr = {"42", "69", "403"};
string result = String.Join(" + ", arr);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output :

> 42 + 69 + 403